# transform() does not transform my data [R]

Tags: r

I have a basic question and it should be answerable without sample data.

In data frame `ert`, `x` and `y` should be numeric, but they are read as characters probably because there are `""` around data values. I can't remove those `""` as the dataset is too large to remove them one by one. Thus, I ran the following code to attempt to transform the character data into numeric data.

```
transform(ert, x = as.numeric(x), y = as.numeric(y))
```

This runs, but when I check `sapply(ert, mode)` it still indicates that `x` and `y` are characters. Why does not `transform` work?

Comment: @李哲源 I'm saying that even if the data has quotes, then R can can still read it as numeric. It only won't be numeric if there is a non-numeric value in that column. So there's more than likely "bad" data in there somewhere which should be addressed rather than simply trying to force/coerce to numeric. Because, yes, there are likely factors and using as.numeric on those rarely results in the desired behavior.

Comment: (1) MrFlick's `read.csv` code shows that R interprets them as `integer`, which is what I expect. (2) The fact that it is not that way for Paul suggests either he is overriding it manually or (more likely) there is something in the file convincing R to do something else. (3) 李哲源's suggestion that they are `factor`s is factual but I suspect immaterial here since the problems are centered on not identifying as numbers and not correctly reassigning them when casting manually with `transform(..., x=as.numeric(x))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `transform` is not in-place. Do an assignment: `ert <- transform(ert, ...)`